# how do i call another function outside my class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i'm trying to setup an event on any change within the form input class

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

DealerRegistration extends React.Component {

    state = {
        business_type  :   'dealer'
       ,business_name  :   ''
       ,manager_fname  :   ''
       ,manager_lname  :   ''
       ,address_1      :   ''
       ,address_2      :   ''
       ,city           :   ''
       ,state          :   ''
       ,zip_code       :   ''
       ,manager_tn     :   ''
       ,manager_email  :   ''
       ,business_ein   :   ''
       ,user_name      :   ''
       ,password       :   '' 
    };

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    render() {
        function DealerRegisterApi(){
            return (
            // step 1: take all the data from the form - put it into json format
            // step 2: post that json to the api
            console.log(dealer_info)
            );
        }
        class RegistrationInput extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                    <input className="block w-full px-1 py-1 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring"
                            type='dealer_registration'
                            id={this.props.id}
                            aria-label={this.props.id}
                            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                            value={this.state}
                            onChange={onChange(e)} //<---i've tried every iteration
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
        return (
        <section className="max-w-2xl p-2 mx-auto bg-white rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800" >
        <div className='p-6 justify-center items-center h-screen flex'>
            <form className='flex' className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-1 mt-0 sm:grid-cols-1">
                <div>
                    <label className="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" id='business_type' type='business_type' placeholder='business' type>business type: </label>
                        <select id="business_type" value={this.state} onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}>
                            <option value="dealer">dealer</option>
                            <option value="broker">broker</option>
                            <option value="other">other</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <RegistrationInput id="business_name"   placeholder="business name"/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_fname"   placeholder="manager first name" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_lname"   placeholder="manager last name" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="address_1"       placeholder="address 1" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="address_2"       placeholder="address 2" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="city"            placeholder="city" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="state"           placeholder="state" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="zip_code"        placeholder="zip code" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_tn"      placeholder="manager phone number" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_email"   placeholder="manager email" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="business_ein"    placeholder="business EIN" />
                    <br></br>
                    <RegistrationInput id="user_name"       placeholder="set user name" />
                    <RegistrationInput id="password"        placeholder="set password" />
                    <br></br>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={DealerRegisterApi}
                    className="bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-700 text-white text-center py-2 px-4 rounded">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </section>
            )    
        }
};
  
export default DealerRegistration
```

**the error i get:**

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: onChange is not defined
```

**when i try something like:**

```
onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}

or

onChange={() => this.onChange()}
```

i also get an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: _this2.onChange is not a function
```

i get that its not within the same class, so there's something fishy about using 'this' possibly? really not sure.

also would be great to get some advice on how to better structure a form like this.

and...
adding this part, because it doesn't want the post to be mostly code - but i'm not sure what else to say

Comment: Why are you defining a component within the render function of another?

Comment: Defining a class inside of the `render` is a really really bad practice.

Comment: @BrianThompson ok that's good to know!  so is that the reason for this issue? because i had it setup a different way without the onChange function, and it was working - but i needed to add state

Comment: Yes that looks like its causing your problem. `this` will refer to `RegistrationInput`, not the `DealerRegistration`. You could assign `this` to a different variable to put it within scope, but this would be really hacky, and there's other problems with defining a component within a component like this. Basically, just move it out of the other class, and pass `onChange` to it as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question:

`onChange` is not available in the scope because you haven't defined a variable by this name.

`this.onChange` is not a function because at that location, `this` refers to an instance of `RegistrationInput` class, which doesn't define the method.

The right thing to do would be to provide `onChange` using component props.

```js
class RegistrationInput extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <input onChange={this.props.onChange} />;
   }
}
// ...
   <RegistrationInput id="business_ein" placeholder="business EIN" onChange={this.onChange} />
```

This will also allow you to move the `RegistrationInput` class definition out of the `render` method. In your case this causes a performance hit since React gets a new version of `RegistrationInput` class on every render, and the DOM is recreated from scratch on every render.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your main question is `onChange` inside `class DealerRegistration` is not available in `class RegistrationInput` because they have different scopes.
Overall, your some critical improvements should be done in your code. The main issue being defining a component inside the `render` method of another component. I made some changes to your code in order to improve. It fully forks. Check here:

```
import React from "react";

class RegistrationInput extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
          <input className="block w-full px-1 py-1 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring"
                  type='text'
                  id={this.props.id}
                  aria-label={this.props.id}
                  placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                  value={this.state}
                  onChange={this.props.change} //<---i've tried every iteration
              />
          </div>
      )
  }
}

class DealerRegistration extends React.Component {

    state = {
        business_type  :   'dealer'
       ,business_name  :   ''
       ,manager_fname  :   ''
       ,manager_lname  :   ''
       ,address_1      :   ''
       ,address_2      :   ''
       ,city           :   ''
       ,state          :   ''
       ,zip_code       :   ''
       ,manager_tn     :   ''
       ,manager_email  :   ''
       ,business_ein   :   ''
       ,user_name      :   ''
       ,password       :   '' 
    };

    // we send a reference to this function to RegistrationInput
    // through props like this: <RegistrationInput change={this.onChange}/>...
    onChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
      });
    };



    render() {
        function DealerRegisterApi(){
            return (
            // step 1: take all the data from the form - put it into json format
            // step 2: post that json to the api
            console.log("dealer_info")
            );
        }

        return (
        <section className="max-w-2xl p-2 mx-auto bg-white rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800" >
        <div className='p-6 justify-center items-center h-screen flex'>
            <form className='flex' className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-1 mt-0 sm:grid-cols-1">
                <div>
                    <label className="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" id='business_type' type='business_type' placeholder='business' type>business type: </label>
                        <select id="business_type" value={this.state} onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}>
                            <option value="dealer">dealer</option>
                            <option value="broker">broker</option>
                            <option value="other">other</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <RegistrationInput id="business_name"   placeholder="business name" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_fname"   placeholder="manager first name" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_lname"   placeholder="manager last name" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="address_1"       placeholder="address 1" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="address_2"       placeholder="address 2" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="city"            placeholder="city" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="state"           placeholder="state" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="zip_code"        placeholder="zip code" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_tn"      placeholder="manager phone number" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="manager_email"   placeholder="manager email" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="business_ein"    placeholder="business EIN" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <br></br>
                    <RegistrationInput id="user_name"       placeholder="set user name" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <RegistrationInput id="password"        placeholder="set password" change={this.onChange}/>
                    <br></br>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={DealerRegisterApi}
                    className="bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-700 text-white text-center py-2 px-4 rounded">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </section>
            )    
        }
};
  
export default DealerRegistration
```

Let me know in the comments if it was helpful for you